# How to post JSON

Tags: android-json, android-async-http

I want to POST `JSON` in the following format and GET response.

Mentioned JSON:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "id": "234576"
    "name": "string"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 2 json objects like:

```
JSONObject parent = new JSONObject();
JSONObject child = new JSONObject();
```

In the child object, put:

```
parent.put("success", true);
child.put("id", "234567");
child.put("name", "string");
parent.put("data", child);
```

and simply call ur service using this parent object.